# Bars are allowed to reject unruly patrons

Tags: word-usage

What does "Bars" mean? Lawyers? Random House Dictionary shows "Bar, the practicing members of the legal profession." So I guess that Bars here might refer to the lawyers who legally represent Twitter.

> MeltedSnowGirl
> Replying to
> @RichardDawkins
> c: Twitter is a private corporation with a Terms of Service Policy that we all agree to when we sign up for an account. It's a "No Shoes, No Shirt, No Mask, No Service" for the electronic world.  **Bars are allowed to reject unruly patrons**, Social Media can do the same thing.

Comment: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/bar

Comment: "The Bar" refer to "lawyers who are allowed to argue a case in a higher court". The problem is that the author in the OP used "bars" - I am not sure whether that is standard or correct English.

Comment: You obviously did not read the link in my previous comment. Let me make it easier for you. **bar** in your sentence means "a place where drinks, especially alcoholic drinks, are sold and drunk, or the area in such a place where the person serving the drinks stands"

Answer (score 1):

"Bar" in this context means "place where alcoholic drinks are sold" It is quite common for people who run bars to remove people who are drunk and disruptive from the building, and employ "bouncers" whose job it is to do this.

"The Bar" is sometimes used to mean "the Barrister profession". Barristers are a type of lawyer who can present legal arguments in high court in the English system and some other places (but not the USA).  It is always singular.  If you want to refer to individual lawyers, use "barrister", but not in the USA which doesn't distinguish solicitors from barristers.

Ultimately both meanings deriver from "bar" meaning "something that blocks the way".  A place that serves alcohol has a "bar" that separates the customers from the bottles, and functions as a table.  And in the medieval law schools (called inns of court) there was a railing that separated undergraduate students (benchers) from those who had graduated. This was called "the bar" and so if you were "called to the bar" you were being invited to graduate. So "the bar" came to mean "the collective of lawyers" by metymony.